# Can not update codeigniter ci_sessions table with custom data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added user_id column to ci_sessions table and trying to update it with user id data on login.

When I try to update ci_sessions table with using an sql command in model, affected rows returns zero. Relevant code is this;

```
public function setUserIdToSession($userId,$sessionId){

    $this->db->set('user_id', $userId, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $sessionId);
    $this->db->update('ci_sessions');

    return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

I tried another way to achieve this problem;

```
public function setUserIdToSession($userId,$sessionId){

    $sql = "UPDATE ci_sessions SET user_id ='$userId' WHERE id='$sessionId'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

This function returns zero as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you trying to update the id?

Comment: Changing the ci_sessions table to hold user data is wrong. It already stores such data. You should be using the code described in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library) about adding, reading and removing session data.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
    $data = array('user_id'=> $userId);
    $this->db->where('id', session_id());
    $this->db->update('ci_sessions', $data)
```